# What to use instead of HTTP_X_XDV in Diazo?

Tags: plone, xdv, deliverance, diazo

I'm approaching to Diazo after a light use of collective.xdv.

Usually in xdv I could use a nice env variable "HTTP_X_XDV" to allow the rendering of certain css file (in portal_css via genericsetup).
What I could use in Diazo?

Thank's
Vito

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of plone.app.theming, you can use this:

`request/HTTP_X_THEME_ENABLED | nothing`

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming